# Using FileType with django custom management commands?

Tags: python, django

I have a CSV file with data I want to import using a custom command from the Django Custom Management commands. I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.10. Here is the code.

```
import csv                                                                                                                              
 import argparse

 from awards.models import Student, HomeRoom
 from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

 homeroom = 'HR 12C'

 class Command(BaseCommand):
     help = "Import students by homeroom."

     def add_arguments(self, parser):
         parser.add_argument('csvfile', nargs='+', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

     def handle(self, *args, **options):
         student_list = []
         hr = HomeRoom.objects.get(name=homeroom)
         with open(options['csvfile']) as csvfile:
             reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
             for row in reader:
                 student_list.append(Student(name=row["Student Name"], studentidnum=row["School ID"], homeroom=hr))
```

Yeah, homeroom is hard-coded. I'd rather pull that value from the filename (which is 'HR 12C.csv') but I'm not sure how to do that. But that's not the real problem. When I run the above code with this command: python manage.py importcsv 'awards/12C.csv' I get the following error:

```
 File "/home/ssidollars/dollars/awards/management/commands/importcsv.py", line 18, in handle
 with open(options['csvfile']) as csvfile:
 TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. It seems to think thinks I'm passing it a list, but... I don't see any lists which it could be. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass only one parameter, change `nargs='+'` to `nargs='?'` to avoid dealing with a list.

Then the `options['csvfile']` object returned by the parser is already a `TextIOWrapper`, no need to open it again.

You could use this way to achieve what you want :

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
     help = "Import students by homeroom."

     def add_arguments(self, parser):
         parser.add_argument('csvfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

     def handle(self, *args, **options):
         student_list = []
         hr = HomeRoom.objects.get(name=homeroom)
         with options['csvfile'] as csvfile:
             reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
             for row in reader:
                 student_list.append(Student(name=row["Student Name"], studentidnum=row["School ID"], homeroom=hr))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. I've never used argparse, and the examples were confusing me so I wasn't sure what was going on there. The code executed perfectly.